# C - Function that counts the number of occurrences of an element in a randomized array

Tags: c, arrays, function, element, find-occurrences

I'm kinda new to programming overall and are currently programming in C, and I'm currently working on a program that first randomizes 10 numbers that are put into an array and prints them out on the screen, and then let the user enter an integer and the program should then check the array and print out how many times the user entered integer occurs in the array, and this is where I'm having trouble.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

//  Function to initialize random numbers.
int Random()                                                            
{
    srand(time(NULL));                                                  //  To initialize the random number generator.
    return 0;                                                           //  Really only the important part from the function, that it returns something.
}

// Generates randome values for the array.
void setRandomNumber(int inputArray[], int arraySize)                   
{
    int i;
    Random();                                                           //  Calls the "Random" function. 
    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)                                      //  Conditions for when/how many times to run the loop.
        inputArray[i] = (rand() % 10) + 1;                              //  What values the array will get, random numbers between 1 and 10.
}

// Function to count the occurrances of an element.
int countElement(int inputArray[], int arraySize, int elementCount)
{

}

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[10];                                                    
    int loop;
    int run = 1;
    int elementCount = 1;
    setRandomNumber(numbers, 10);                                       //  Calls the "setRandomNumber" fucntion to set random values to the floats in the array. 
    countElement(numbers, 10, elementCount);

    for (loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)                                   //  Prints out the already randomized values of the array "numbers"
        printf("Number: %d\n", numbers[loop]);

    printf("\nWhat to search for: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &elementCount);                                       //  Takes user input on what number to check.
    printf("The number %d occurs %d times.\n", elementCount, countElement);

    return 0;


}
```

We are required to use functions and the functionheader must look like this `int countElement(int inputArray[], int arraySize, int elementCount)` and in this case it's the `countElement` function that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: What is the problem? Have you attempted to write the `countElement` function?

Comment: One major problem you have is in the line `printf("The number %d occurs %d times.\n", elementCount, countElement);` - where the last argument, as you have it, will be the *address* of the `countElement` function. To get the function's returned value, you need to specify the function with arguments, like this: `countElement(numbers, 10, elementCount)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple

```
int countElement(int inputArray[], int arraySize, int elementCount)
{
    int count = 0l

    for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++ )
    {
        if ( inputArray[i] == elementCount ) ++count; 
    }

    return count;
}
```

The function can be called like

```
printf("The number %d occurs %d times.\n", elementCount, 
                                           countElement( numbers, 10, elementCount ) );
```

Though it would be more correctly to declare the function like

```
 size_t countElement( const int inputArray[], size_t arraySize, int elementCount );
```

Comment: The code runs when I added the things you said to the "countElement" function, and i changed the "printf". But now each time I enter a value it just returns that the number occurs 10 times even tho it don't. Any suggestions? Thanks btw for the first part.

Comment: @ConfusedChicken4 Check whether in this statement if ( inputArray[i] == elementCount ) ++count; you are using the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator as in the original statement.

Comment: How do you mean? (started programming 3 weeks ago and learned about functions today) this is currently how it looks in my code "if (inputArray[i] == elementCount)"

Comment: Nvm found the problem. I did not have a "return count;" at the end of the function. Thanks for the help